# kotlin: how to use the Intermediate collection when do stream operations

Tags: kotlin

for example

```
val coordinates: Array<IntArray> = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]

coordinates
   .map {it[0]} 
   .all {it == x[0]}
```

x means the map result of coordinates. I want use it in the 'all' step, how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "x means the map result of coordinates"? The map result of `coordinates` would be `[1, 1, 1]`. Is that what you want `x` to be?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 1):

You could just write this

```
coordinates
   .map {it[0]} 
   .all {it == coordinates[0][0]}
```

Or if you don't want to directly refer to coordinates again, maybe insert a `let` like

```
coordinates
    .map { it[0] }
    .let { x -> x.all { it == x[0] } }
```

Although for your specific use case I probably would just do

```
coordinates
    .all { it[0] == coordinates[0][0] }
```

Comment: thanks, I understand,  that workaround works. I think there's no elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can just declare a `val` called `x`:

```
val x = coordinates.map { it[0] }
val result = x.all { it == x[0] }
```

Or if you want to do it in one expression, you can use the scope function `run` or `let`:

```
val result = coordinates.map { it[0] }.run {
    all { it == this[0] }
}
```

or:

```
val result = coordinates.map { it[0] }.let { x ->
    x.all { it == x[0] }
}
```

Though, if you just want to check if the whole list has exactly one unique value, I think this is more readable:

```
val result = coordinates.map { it[0] }.distinct().size == 1
```

The above doesn't short-circuit like `all`. A shortcircuiting version would need `Sequence`:

```
val result = coordinates
    .asSequence()
    .map { it[0] }
    .distinct().take(2).count() == 1
```

Comment: thanks. the distanct method is elegant, and using shortcircuiting is inspiring.